# C# background thread property missing

Tags: c#, multithreading

i want to configure my Thread to be background thread, why this property missing in my Thread ?

```
    ThreadStart starter = delegate { openAdapterForStatistics(_device); };
    new Thread(starter).Start();

public void openAdapterForStatistics(PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice)
{
    using (PacketCommunicator statCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)) //open the output adapter
    {
        statCommunicator.Mode = PacketCommunicatorMode.Statistics; //put the interface in statstics mode                
        statCommunicator.ReceiveStatistics(0, statisticsHandler);

    }
}
```

i have try:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(openAdapterForStatistics(_device));
```

but i have got 2 compilation errors:

> 1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments
> 2. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

and i don't know why

Comment: i think it's because you are supposed to pass a delegate for parameterized function. not the function. in your case starter.

Comment: Try `Thread thread = new Thread(()=>openAdapterForStatistics(_device));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the background thing, I don't see how you expect to set it since you're not keeping a reference to the thread. Should look like this:

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { openAdapterForStatistics(_device); };
Thread t = new Thread(starter);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

This

```
Thread thread = new Thread(openAdapterForStatistics(_device));
```

won't work because you're supposed to pass in a method that takes `object` as parameter, while you're actually passing the result of a **method call**. So you could do this:

```
public void openAdapterForStatistics(object param)
{
    PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice = (PacketDevice)param;
    using (PacketCommunicator statCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)) //open the output adapter
    {
        statCommunicator.Mode = PacketCommunicatorMode.Statistics; //put the interface in statstics mode                
        statCommunicator.ReceiveStatistics(0, statisticsHandler);

    }
}
```

and:

```
Thread t = new Thread(openAdapterForStatistics);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start(_device);
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `BackgroundWorker` class, which is specifically designed for use like your case.  A task you wish to accomplish in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
PacketDevice selectedOutputDeviceValue = [some value here];
Thread wt = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.openAdapterForStatistics));
wt.Start(selectedOutputDeviceValue);
```

Comment: That won't work actually, because `ParameterizedThreadStart` expects an `object` parameter.

Comment: simple, modify the method openAdapterForStatistics(object _obj) to accept object.